# How to access SObject returned from web service?

Tags: javascript, custom-button, webservices, sobject

So, I'm calling a web service via JavaScript:

```
let opportunity = sforce.apex.execute("OpportunityWebService", "cloneOpportunity", {opportunityId: "{!Opportunity.Id}"});
```

The web service looks like this:

```
global class OpportunityWebService {
    webService static Opportunity cloneOpportunity(Id opportunityId) {
        Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity(<insert stuff here>);
        insert opportunity;
        return opportunity;
    }
}
```

Now I want to access the Id (and other values) of that newly created Opportunity like this:

```
alert(opportunity.Id);
```

But this doesn't work. Interestingly, this does work:

```
alert(opportunity[0].Id);
```

Why?

Comment: What does your apex class return? Please add OpportunityWebService class pseudo code?

Comment: Good idea. Added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Salesforce does not recommend using Javascript Buttons anymore. Javascript buttons have Security risks, and hence in lightning, it is discouraged. Check the docs [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=vJqtFcOX17c)

It looks like you always get an array when `sforce.apex.execute` is used and the first array has the response. Hence use the below code to get it working.

```
let opportunity = sforce.apex.execute("OpportunityWebService", "cloneOpportunity", {opportunityId: "{!Opportunity.Id}"});
  if(opportunity.length > 0) {
    console.log(opportunity[0].Id);
  }
```

Comment: Yes. It's pseudocode. Of course, I insert it. It has an Id any everything.

Comment: @Semmel Can you just return the Id instead of the opportunity and see if it makes a difference? You might want to query it again as well before you return it?

Comment: I guess this will work as I'm doing this in other web services. But my question particularly is how I can access a returned SObject.

Comment: Can you do a console log here console.log(JSON.Stringify(opportunity));

Comment: `[{"Id":"0060E00000QUn9JQAT","Account":{"Id":"0010E00000pY9t7QAC","FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar","RecordTypeId":"01258000000VMk9AAG"}}]`

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: @Semmel I think you oversimplified your example. If it's returning that, your method must be returning `List<Opportunity>`; if you returned `Opportunity`, then your JS should have worked.

Comment: So - this actually works. But I'm not returning a list. How is this possible?

Comment: good question. I will need to investigate it? Are you sure it's not listed you return?

Comment: Well - it says `webService static Opportunity` so even if I tried to return a list it shouldn't work, right?

Comment: Correct yes it should not return list ideally but will check now to see why it is list

Comment: @Semmel Check the updated response. Note the response will always be an array that's how it is implemented. It is a bug that it returns an array.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thanks for the clarification! I think that is really weird. Is this really a bug? Or by design? I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: @Semmel Docs are thin but I think it’s a bug.